# Making Folders with Electron JS

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I am using Electron and Electron Forge to build a desktop download app.  When in debug mode `npm start` I can make folders without a problem.  Once the project is packaged and I run the .dmg on OSX I get an error when the App goes to make a folder.

Error -

> Uncaught Exception:
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/Users/folder/dl2/test2'
>      at Error (native)
>      at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:922:18)

Code to make folders

```
if (!fs.existsSync(dirpath)) {
   fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(dirpath), { recursive: true });
}
```

Answered Bellow

Comment: Can you output and compare the content of `dirpath` in your debug and production apps. It might be different from what you expect in production.

Comment: You mean the variable value of `dirpath`, they match I'm using a dialog box to pick the folder.  Neither debug or complied require the applications path

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a node issue, I found the answer here - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27293

I used the following block

```
function mkdirp(dir) {
  if (fs.existsSync(dir)) { return true }
  const dirname = path.dirname(dir)
  mkdirp(dirname);
  fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
mkdirp(dirpath);
```